# "start stopwatch" when "screen on" & "pause stopwatch" when "screen off"

Tags: java, android, database, timer, stopwatch

i want to build app where;

- "stopwatch" will be active when the phone screen is open
- "stopwatch" will pause the screen when the phone is close
- every time "stopwatch" pause, data will be recorded [in the records for one day]
- Every 24 hours the application is started, all the records are stored

for example:

- on screen: 00:00:00
- off screen: 3:10:00 [data recorded]
- on screen: 3:10:00
- off screen: 8:40:00 [data recorded]

consider this is a record for one day (24 hours), and a database for that day recorded.

The problem I face now;

- I do not know how to start a "stopwatch" when the screen is open
- I do not know how to pause "stopwatch" when the screen is close

need help .. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following:

Create a BroadcastReceiver

```
public class ScreenStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_TURNED_OFF.equals(action)) {
            // Screen is off
        } else if (Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT.equals(action)) {
            // Screen is on
        }
    }
}
```

Register is either via Code or in the manifest

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);

context.registerReceiver(mScreenReceiver, filter, null, null);
```

And basically you're all set to do your thing.

Comment: hmmm. nice ! but how to insert a stopwatch code with code that you have given this. hm.

Comment: You start the watch when screen is on and stop it when screen is off - the you drop it into the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it very easily by:

in `onResume()` you just start the stopwatch..

in `onPause()` you should stop stopwatch and record data in db or at your preferred location.